# New label class in iPhone with custom font

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

As it seems that it is not possible to apply a custom font through Interface Builder, I tried to define a new UILabel-derived class and set in its - (id)init method the custom font I'd like to use: this doesn't lead to the expected result as the font used at runtime seems to be still the 'Helvetica' (my custom font is 'african' and it works if set via code).

Here is my UILabel-derived snippet:

```
- (id)init {
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"african" size:10];
    [self setFont:font];    

    return self;
}
```

Therefore I'm currently solving the problem by forcing the font via code:

```
NSLog(@"Before FONT NAME IS ------------> %@", myLabel.font.fontName);  
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"african" size:10];
[myLabel setFont:font];
myLabel.text = @"HELLO!";
NSLog(@"After FONT NAME IS ------------> %@", myLabel.font.fontName);
```

The printout is the following:

```
Before FONT NAME IS ------------> Helvetica
After FONT NAME IS ------------> African
```

It seems that the default font I set in the init method is overwritten: where else should I set it?

Comment: Actually, it is possible to change the font from Interface Builder. Just go to the Fonts menu -> Show Fonts. Then, select your label and choose your new font.

Comment: I tried this and even though I can add the new font and use it on IB, at runtime I still have the wrong one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use your init function like that "self" will have no value… All init functions have to look like this

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Your init code here
    }
    return self;
}
```

Additionally make sure you'll override "initWithFrame:" too, and perhaps "initWithCoder:" if you want to use it from IB.